# SPA with separation of frontend and backend

Tags: single-page-application

Which javascript framework can make SPA web application frontend with separation of frontend and backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **AngularJS** is the JavaScript framework, that has been developed for creating **S.P.A.** (*single-page-applications*).

For it to work, you need to have basic knowledge of the following things:

1. **JavaScript**
2. **HTML**
3. **CSS**

It does have separation of contents between front-end and back-end.

Basically, it's a front-end framework; it can consume the services through RESTful API's.
You can read more about it [**here**](https://angularjs.org/).

Although, this is not the only one that enables you to create SPA, on googling you can find many of them, since I am working with this, I have referenced you its name.